# Trouble with fine tuning legend key in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to have legend keys match exactly the plot using the `theme()` and `guides()` functions.

Starting with this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mpg)

mpg$year <- as.numeric(mpg$year)
means <- tapply(mpg$displ, list(mpg$year), FUN = mean)
means <- as.data.frame(means)
means$year <- as.numeric(row.names(means))
names(means)[1] <- "displ"

p1 <- 
  ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = displ)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = "points")) +
  geom_errorbar(data = means, aes(ymin = displ, ymax = displ, 
    color = "mean")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1998, 2008))

p1
```

I get a plot where I can modify legend keys using:

```
p1 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA), 
legend.title = element_blank()) + 
guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = 
list(shape=c(NA, 16), linetype=c(1, 0), fill = c(NA, NA))))
```

Getting the desired result:
[image: Legend keys matching plot]

However, when the plot also contains `geom_ribbon()` the same method fails:

```
p2 <- 
  ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = displ)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = "points")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 3, ymax = 4, color = "ribbon"), 
    fill = "green", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(data = means, aes(ymin=displ, ymax=displ, 
    color="mean")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1998, 2008))

p2 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA), 
  legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = 
    list(shape=c(NA, 16, NA), linetype=c(1, 0, 0), 
    fill = c(NA, NA, "green"))))
```

[image: Plot with incorrect legend keys]

To be clear: I want the legend key representing the mean to show as just a straight red line, like in the first plot, no border, no diagonal.

(I realize I could use stat_summary() instead of creating a separate dataframe, but that won't work for my actual project).

Thanks for any advice,

Lasse

---

Comment: Do you _need_ to set the color for the ribbon in `aes`?

Comment: I think so. I need a legend telling what the ribbon shows, and to my knowledge the only way to do that is to create a constant `color` in `aes`

Comment: You can use fill instead, which will avoid the lines in the legend.

Comment: You min fill instead of color inside `aes()` in `geom_ribbon()`? For me, that produces an error?

Comment: More precisly: Using fill instead of color loses the ribbon legend altogether

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit of a hack, but I removed the legend from `geom_ribbon` and added the ribbon color as a point type (pch = 15) in the legend.
The colors are not perfect yet, but I bet you can manage.

```
p2 <- 
  ggplot(mpg, aes(x = year, y = displ)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(color = "points")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 3, ymax = 4, color = "ribbon"), 
              fill = "green", alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_errorbar(data = means, aes(ymin=displ, ymax=displ, 
                                  color="mean")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1998, 2008))

p2 + theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA), 
           legend.title = element_blank()) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = 
                                list(shape=c(NA, 16, 15), linetype=c(1, 0, 0), 
                                     color = c("red", "green", "green"),
                                     alpha = c(1,1,.5),
                                     size = c(1,2,6))))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thanks, but when I run your code, I don't get your plot? I get all three legend keys with a green fill?

Comment: Yes. I simply copy-pasted your code, including `show.legend = FALSE`. 
I'm running:
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

ggplot2_1.0.1

Thanks for you effort, @Wietze314

Comment: I have tested this on R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) and ggplot2 v2.1.0 on R running on an Rstudio Server.

Comment: On R-fiddle (3.1.2) I can see the issue you are having. I have no clue why there is a difference between the versions....